# is there anyway to remove laravel telescope tables without running another migration?

Tags: laravel-5, database-migration

I have completely removed this package from my project but the tables are still there, is another way to remove them too?

Comment: Databases? You mean tables? Use your favorite database UI or CLI tool to remove tables. Or, if the telescope migrations have been removed you could run a fresh migration (will drop **all** tables/data and start afresh)

Comment: yes, I meant tables, I don't know why I wrote database. anyway thanks for your response